# Is Devise's authenticate_user protecting against someone spoofing a user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a `create` method that allows non-signed in users to purchase things. So I'm considering skipping `authenticate_user`. But, if `authenticate_user` is verifying that a signed in user is who they say they are then I'll just conditionally skip if `!user_signed_in?`

EDIT: Does it make it less secure for the signed in users if I don't authenticate them using Devise's `authenticate_user!` method? Or, does it add any more security for a signed in user to run `authenticate_user!`

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is...

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're asking.  Authenticate_user via devise is just using Rails sessions and cookies.  As of now it is not feasible to brute-force a cookie so authentice_user is secure...Skip authenticate_user for only the actions where you're allowing users to remain anonymous via a "before_action :authenticate_user, except: [:this_action, :or_this_action] #in your controller

Comment: I think that answers my question, but I added a little clarification to the text